# Exception forwarding Jena ResultSet

Tags: jsp, servlets, path, rdf

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String filename = "/WEB-INF/TesteLOM2.rdf";
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();

    InputStream in = context.getResourceAsStream(filename);
        if (in != null) {
            Model model = ModelFactory.createMemModelMaker()
                    .createDefaultModel();
            model.read(in, null);
            // null base URI, since model URIs are absolute
            in.close();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> lista = (List<String>) request.getSession()
        .getAttribute("sugestao");
    String palavrachave = null;
    for (Iterator<String> iter = lista.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {

    palavrachave = iter.next();
    // Creates a query....
    String queryString =

    // ( SPARQL stuff here...}

    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

    // get the results...

    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
    request.setAttribute("results", results);
    /*
    * Compiler says error is in next line
    * Got this exception: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    * as I tried to forward results to a jsp page...
    */

    request.getRequestDispatcher(VIEW).forward(request, response);
    // ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
    qe.close();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I got partially solved. I did some (obvious) changings: QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("results", results);
    //request.setAttribute("results", results);
    
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
    qe.close();

   }
   request.getAttribute("results");
   request.getRequestDispatcher(VIEW).forward(request, response); But I can't get result set rendered in JSP. So, help is still needed....

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc for [HttpServletResponse](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) it would appear you want to be calling `response.getOutputStream()` to get the actual HTTP response stream to write to rather than using `System.out`

Then you also may want to be using a different overload of the [ResultSetFormatter](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ResultSetFormatter.html) `out()` or `output()` method in order to have more control over the results format e.g.

```
ResultSetFormatter.output(response.getOutputStream(), results, ResultSetFormat.syntaxXML)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, RobV. Of course it helps. It seems to me that some problems arise from a misunderstanding of the workings of Jena  ResultSetFomater. It is an iterator, so, when I call it from the JSP, its works have already done, so  I got no results there. I got a suggestion to create a copy o if (I supposed that it could circumvent this, calling "getSession().setAttribute ("results", results). However it does not work. I have to perform some code changes... and see what happens...